# What is a good way to run my Docker containerized application as a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, docker

More and more applications have manuals telling you to preferrably run it within a docker container. But if you want an application to follow the system runlevels of the linux operating system that your docker container is running on and be controllable with commands like '`sudo service myservice start`' and '`systemctl enable myservice`' then it is much easier to make it a systemd service. Running it without docker can be cumbersome. I could narrow this question to Java Spring Boot Applications because that's my main use case for the applications I write myself, but I would rather come to a more generic approach to do this in a way that it is:

- easy to configure
- survives reboots gracefully
- keeps most or all the advantages of systemd control

Ofcourse there will be reasons why I should not want this approach and I can guess some of the responses that will follow. I am interested in that. Things should be as simple as possible, but not simpler (Einstein something). But describing a simple approach that will work could benefit the Linux and Docker community.

In response to some earlier answers below (thanks for the valuable feedback!): I prefer to control all individual applications on my operating system by one means of control. By default that would be systemd because that's the default of the operating system for that. I know using a container is a bit of a different paradigm then running it on the OS itself, but I don't really know what rule I would be breaking if I would create a systemd service like 'homeassistant-container', that controls starting and stopping a docker container with (in this case) 'homeassistant' as an application within that container

Comment: You shouldn't be running systemd inside the container. The container should be run as a systemd service. I don't think Docker has (or had) good integration for that, something like Podman might better.

Comment: make a service file in ``/etc/systemd/system/'' dir

Comment: @muru: I don't want to be running systemd inside the container. I want the container to be controlled by systemd. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: See [this blog post](https://blog.container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd) for some hints - it appears there are several things to consider.

Comment: @ArturMeinild: that seems like the best answer. If you post it as the answer, then I will mark it as the best answer

Comment: In that case I think Podman is definitely the way to go. Since Podman supports the same OCI standards as Docker, you wouldn't have to change the image, just how you run it. But it seems the old way of generating systemd units is deprecated in favour of a new Quadlet system, but I'm familiar with it to write an answer about it. Maybe in a few days after I play around with it. See https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/20218

Comment: @muru: Yes I invite you to write a good answer about it. ArthurMeinild also seems to have a working answer. It might become a bit of a beauty contest which is the best one. We'll see what other people think

Comment: I actually think Podman would be best suited for `systemd` units, since it runs daemonless. Also, the blog I link to is quite old, and I don't feel I know enough about this to provide a sufficient answer. 

Comment: Yep, I found this document as well: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/building_running_and_managing_containers/assembly_porting-containers-to-systemd-using-podman_building-running-and-managing-containers. I suggest @muru gives the simple Podman suggestion as an answer and I can mark it as the best answer. Reputation credit where it is due.

Comment: Aargh, typo in previous comment, it's supposed to be: I'm **not** familiar enough with Quadlet to write an answer about it (yet, anyway).

Comment: If it's just one container, have you considered just using systemctl on the entire Docker daemon?

Comment: I have, but then you start and shutdown all docker containers at once. I want to be able to start and stop multiple individual containers as a service. Podman seems to be the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example: you want to install redis containerized, but start/stoppable as a systemd service:

- Install podman:

  `sudo apt install podman`
- Get the container from docker.io you want to run as a servic. In this example: redis

  `sudo podman pull docker.io/redis`
- Run the image as a container. In this case, we also expose reddits default port (6379) on the host itself with the same portnumber with the option: `-p 6379:6379`

  `sudo podman run -d --name redis_server -p 6379:6379 redis`
- Generate a systemd file with podman:

  `sudo podman generate systemd --new --name --files redis_server`
- Start this service by default at each boot:

  `sudo systemctl enable container-redis_server.service`
- Start the service:

  `sudo systemctl start container-redis_server.service`
- Check the status of the service:

  `sudo systemctl status container-redis_server.service`

The output will look something like:

```
    ● container-redis_server.service - Podman container-redis_server.service
         Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/container-redis_server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-01-25 18:35:01 CET; 1s ago
           Docs: man:podman-generate-systemd(1)
        Process: 104769 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /run/container-redis_server.service.ctr-id (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       Main PID: 104896 (conmon)
          Tasks: 2 (limit: 37994)
         Memory: 1.0M
            CPU: 269ms
         CGroup: /system.slice/container-redis_server.service
                 └─104896 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c dac4fdfcab837e3aee559da856ee1a1827ed319b1c113d96bd3d828c9a4edf57 -u dac4fdfcab837e3aee559da856ee1a1827ed319b1c113d96bd3d828c9a4edf57 -r /usr/sbin/runc -b /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/dac4fdfcab837e3aee>
...
17:35:01.666 * Ready to accept connections tcp
```

As #muru described in his comments, 'Podman' turns out to be suited to solve this problem. I added the priceless remark about 'podman generate systemd' from #user68186. Using podman quadlets might even be better. I will research on that option later.

The solution above was heavily inspired by the link below, just leaving out the SELinux bit, because SELinux is not common to Ubuntu.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/running_containers_as_systemd_services_with_podman

Comment: You should also in your answer explain how to set this up, for the answer to really help others here. 

Comment: I hope this is what you expect. Please feel free to comment

Comment: Excellent now! 

Comment: @user68186: I will try a solution with you sugesstions and will see if it's more straightforward. It sounds it is. You are free to give the answer here yourself, if you like to. Or you prefer me to put in the effort?

Comment: I have converted my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe running Pihole in podman using systemd. I have been running it for a while, and it requires some configuration. I assume you have already installed podman. If not install podman:

```
sudo apt install podman
```

See https://learnubuntu.com/install-podman/ for more details.

## 1. pull and start up Pihole in podman

Pihole will need two container volumes to persist data, we can create them with podman:

```
sudo podman volume create pihole_pihole
sudo podman volume create pihole_dnsmasq
```

The following command will pull Pihole and run it:

```
sudo podman run -d --name=pihole --hostname=peppy \
    --label "io.containers.autoupdate=registry" \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
    --dns=127.0.0.1 \
    --dns=1.1.1.1 \
    -e TZ=America/New_York \
    -e SERVERIP=192.168.x.y \
    -e WEBPASSWORD=SecretPassword \
    -v pihole_pihole:/etc/pihole:Z \
    -v pihole_dnsmasq:/etc/dnsmasq.d:Z \
    -p 127.0.0.1:80:80/tcp \
    -p 127.0.0.1:443:443/tcp \
    -p 53:53/tcp \
    -p 53:53/udp \
    docker.io/pihole/pihole:latest
```

Note: The whole thing is a single command. the `\` breaks it into multiple lines.

You will have to change the timezone, SERVERIP, and WEBPASSWORD to suit your needs.

The port settings:

```
    -p 127.0.0.1:80:80/tcp \
    -p 127.0.0.1:443:443/tcp \
```

assume the computer in which podman will run has a GUI desktop and a browser app installed. These settings will only allow web-admin access to Pihole from the `localhost`. If you want to access the web-admin of Pihole from another computer in the same network or across the internet, adjust these options accordingly.

The above command will get your container up and running. You can check with:

```
sudo podman ps
```

Two options are needed for automatic updates.

```
--label "io.containers.autoupdate=registry" \
```

and

```
docker.io/pihole/pihole:latest
```

The part, `docker.io/pihole/pihole:latest` could be shortened to `pihole:latest`. However, you will need the explicit location to pull the image from if you want systemd to keep the image automatically updated.

## Set it up in systemd

First generate the systemd service file with the following command:

```
sudo podman generate systemd --new --name --files pihole
```

You will see this notice in the output:

```
DEPRECATED command:
It is recommended to use Quadlets for running containers and pods under systemd.
```

I have not looked into Quadlets much. It is the newer way of integrating podman and systemd.

`--new` will pull the latest version of pihole every time the computer starts or the systemd service is restarted. You may not want this, but it is needed for auto updating the container image.

`--files` will create a file called `container-pihole.service` in your current directory.

Copy the service file to its rightful place:

```
sudo cp container-pihole.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

Enable and start the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now container-pihole.service
```

Now your container should startup when the system reboots.

## 3. Automatic update of container images

You will have to enable and start the podman auto-update service and timer:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now podman-auto-update.service
sudo systemctl enable --now podman-auto-update.timer
```

This will keep all the podman (docker) container images up to date. You may look into the `timer` file to adjust the frequency.

Hope this helps

Comment: I see how this 'podman generate systemd' is making things easier . Though your example might not be the easiest one around. I will flag it the preferred answer for now. At least until somebody comes up with a good Quadlets description maybe ...

Comment: On second thought I have withdrawn this as preferred answer, because I think it's rather dangerous that you take an example that routes all http(s) traffic to the pihole container. That is not really a safe example to learn about using podman for this purpose I think ...

Comment: @Maarten You may close those ports by not using the respective options if you don't want to use the web-admin portal for Pihole. You don't have to use the WEBPASSWORD then. You can map ports 80 and 443 to some higher level ports. None of these options are central to your question of using docker containers with systemd. Whether you use `podman generate` or `quadlet` the options you use are specific to your needs and the need of the container image you want to run.

Comment: @Maarten I have adjusted the answer to mitigate your safety concerns.